# How to add fields to JSON object without them existing?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JObject that I am trying to add fields to in a way like this:

```cs
JObject dataObject = new JObject();
dataObject[currentSection][key] = val;
```

`currentSection`, `key` and `val` are all strings, I want it so when its all serialized at the end that it looks something like this:

```json
{
    "currentSection": {
        "key": "value"
    }
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JObject.Add()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Add.htm) method to add a property to `JObject`.

1. Create a `JObject` for the nested object.
2. Add property to the nested object.
3. Add property with nested object to root `JObject`.

```cs
JObject dataObject = new JObject();
        
JObject nestedObj = new JObject();
nestedObj.Add(key, val);

dataObject.Add(currentSection, nestedObj);
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JR670P)

Answer (score 1):

You have one nested json object inside of the another one. So you have to create a nested currentSection json object before assigning a key to currrentSection

```
    string currentSection = "currentSection";
    string key = "key";
    string val = "val";

    JObject dataObject = new JObject();
    dataObject[currentSection] = new JObject();
    dataObject[currentSection][key] = val;
```

or you can do the same in one line

```
var dataObject = new JObject { [currentSection] = new JObject { [key] = val } };
```

json

```
var json = dataObject.ToString();

{
  "currentSection": {
    "key": "val"
  }
}
```